# 'Primary Expression Expected' in JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery. I'm trying to get my Json data to be stored on my Web Page as a HTML table. If I use the following code it works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("getAllFilms?format=json", function(data){
var filmInfo = '';
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    filmInfo += '<tr>';
    filmInfo += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
    filmInfo += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
    filmInfo += '<td>'+value.review+'</td>';
    filmInfo += '<td>'+value.stars+'</td>';
    filmInfo += '<td>'+value.director+'</td>';
    filmInfo += '<td>'+value.year+'</td>';
    filmInfo += '<tr>';
});
$('#table').append(filmInfo);
});

});
```

However, I would like this to be in a JavaScript file so that I can call this function when the user clicks a button. I tried the following but I get the error 'Primary Expression Expected'. Any ideas?

```
function allFilmsJsonTable(){
  $.getJSON("getAllFilms?format=json", function(data){
    var filmInfo = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        filmInfo += '<tr>';
        filmInfo += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
        filmInfo += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
        filmInfo += '<td>'+value.review+'</td>';
        filmInfo += '<td>'+value.stars+'</td>';
        filmInfo += '<td>'+value.director+'</td>';
        filmInfo += '<td>'+value.year+'</td>';
        filmInfo += '<tr>';
    });
    $('#table').append(filmInfo);
  });

});
```

Comment: Firstly, where is that error coming from? It's not a JS error. Secondly, Javascript and Java are two very different things so I've retagged your question. Lastly please copy+paste the actual code in to the question so we can easily create working examples to test from. Images of code are not helpful.

Comment: Please post code not pictures, so others can reproduce something. Also you can bind a function to an event for a button or any other things. https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: In your second picture you have an extra `);` at the end which needs to be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've updated it to show the code. I did try and remove the }); but it still comes up with an error in the .js file. When I hover over the error it says 'No Suggestions Available'

Comment: Edit: My mistake. I deleted too much! It seems to be working now, thankyou!